# Thinking process behind proving $\exists$ solution to $f(x) = x$ when f is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

[Real Analysis; prove $f(x)=x$ has at least one solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237290/real-analysis-prove-fx-x-has-at-least-one-solution)

Here is a solution. I proved initially by doing contradiction, assuming $g(x) = x$ , $\forall x\in$ domain of f, either $f(x) > g(x)$ or $f(x) < g(x)$.

But it seems much easier and simpler to pick a $g(x) = f(x) - x$ and prove it, as in the link. My question is, how do you come up with the process of finding this $g(x)$?

Comment: You should have recalled the lesson of "moving all terms involving the unknown you want to solve for to one side", e.g. if you are asked to solve $x+1=2x-3$ you start by moving all $x$'s to one side, that you learnt in primary/secondary school algebra.  After that it is very natural to come up with $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

Comment: ahhh thank you. When I do these proofs I"m like to what extent can I use "regular" algebra solving methods.

Comment: Pretty much to what you need. If in doubt, you can always prove used property from axioms of $\mathbb{R}$. For example, to get from $f(x) = x$ to $f(x) + (-x) = 0$ we use axiom $a = b \Rightarrow a + c = b + c$ (with $a$ been $f(x)$ and $c$ been $-x$), axiom $a = b \wedge b = c \Rightarrow a = c$ (with $a$ been $f(x) + (-x)$, $b$ been $x + (-x)$ and $c$ been $0$) and axiom $x + (-x) = 0$.